# Asynchronously update vaadin components

Tags: java, multithreading, button, vaadin

I have this code for updating vaadin button's caption every 3 seconds.

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            logger.debug("adding l to button's caption");
            btn.setCaption(eventsButton.getCaption() + "l");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
Timer t = new Timer(true);
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 3000);
```

However, it can't change button's caption although it is executed every 3 seconds(judging by the log file). How can I access vaadin's GUI components from another thread?

Comment: found the solution - using ICEPusher addon solves this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an addon named ICEPush which does exactly what I needed.

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably comprehensive discussion of the problem, and the various solutions can be found [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/231271); Redux: 'vanilla' Vaadin simply follows a user initiated request-response paradigm.

You'll need to use an add-on to initiate changes in the browser from the server.

Aside : you should synchronize on the application object when updating components from your own threads (as opposed to the normal request thread) - as you may get 'Sync' errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way Vaadin works, asynchronous UI changes made on the server side are not reflected on the client. The [refresher addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/refresher) makes it possible to make UI changes, even if the user does not start a transaction.

```
final Refresher refresher = new Refresher();
refresher.setRefreshInterval(3000);
addComponent(refresher);

refresher.addListener(new RefreshListener() {    
    @Override
    public void refresh(final Refresher source) {
        try {
            logger.debug("adding l to button's caption");
            btn.setCaption(eventsButton.getCaption() + "l");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is possible only with version 1.1.1 and it doesn't work with current version 1.2.